# Why is g++ not able to compile tuples?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  tuple<string, string, string> x;
  x = make_tuple("hi", "a", "b");
  cout << get<0>(x) << endl << endl;

}
```

I've been having difficulties with my program, so I wrote a simpler one and even this does not work. I do not understand why there is a problem after reviewing the documentation several times. It also compiles fine on XCode but for some reason breaks down on g++.

Here is the full error message:

> test.cpp:6:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'tuple'
>
> tuple x;
>
> ^
>
> test.cpp:6:9: error: unexpected type name 'string': expected
>   expression
>
> tuple x;
>
> ```
>     ^
> ```
>
> test.cpp:7:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'x'
>
> x = make_tuple("hi", "a", "b");
>
> ^
>
> test.cpp:7:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'make_tuple'
>
> x = make_tuple("hi", "a", "b");
>
> ```
>   ^
> ```
>
> test.cpp:8:11: error: reference to overloaded function could not be
>   resolved; did you mean to call it?   cout << get<0>x << endl << endl;

The command I am using is g++ test.cpp

Comment: Probably an older version of g++.

Comment: Try adding `-std=c++11`

Comment: Try adding parentheses.

Comment: But It can compile c++11 just fine?

Comment: Also, include `string`

Comment: string was included in the original program.

Comment: @LogicStuff what parenthesis are you speaking of

Comment: It looks like all you need is `get<0>(x)` instead of `get<0>x`.

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6209067/2564301, but the OP did not look further into this after finding a solution that worked around it.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wOTQuJ2dLXcBg5Kk) after fixing the missing `#include <string>` and the missing parans in `get<0>(x)`. Looks like you need to upgrade your compiler.

Comment: You should have included `<string>` then, because now we're all looking at that as the cause.

Comment: No, `<iostream>` is not required to include `<string>`. It is allowed to, but not required to.

Comment: [Do I have to include string beside iostream ..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506095/do-i-have-to-use-include-string-beside-iostream)

Comment: Thanks, It was the -std=c++11 that did the trick. Didn't know it was necessary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `#include <string>`.

Possibly (depending on your version og gcc) you also need `-std=c++11` on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The tuple is fine; what you're trying to make it a tuple *of* is not.

**You did not `#include <string>`!**

Thus the word "string" means nothing to your compiler, and it has no idea what you want it to do. It can't even tell that you meant it to be a type, so it can't tell that by the word "tuple" you meant "std::tuple". So on, and so forth…